# How to make images of Docker containers for Python, R and MongoDB work together

Tags: python, r, mongodb, docker, shinydashboard

The stack I selected for my project are Python, R and MongoDB. However, I'd like to adopt Docker for this project but when I did my research on the internet, I pretty much found example for MySQL with PHP or Wordpress. So, I'm curious to know where I can find tutorials or example for using containers with Python, R, and MongoDB or any idea on how to put them together. What will the Dockerfile will be like? Especially, in my project, R used for data processing and data visualisation will be called from Python used for data collector as a sub-module for data cleaning as well.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Learn docker compose https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Comment: probably your Python, R, and MongoDB would each be separate containers (so you can version/deploy/scale them separately). they communicate over the network. "linking" containers simplifies that. you can use docker-compose to describe how to deploy a stack of services that work together: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358933/docker-containers-how-do-they-work-together but to be honest, docker-compose doesn't help much with things like "wait for a certain container to be ready before I start sending requests to it"; this logic will have to be application-level or on container startup.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**:
Split them in multiple docker images and run them all using `docker-compose` from a YAML that will set them all up easier.

There's probably already an image for each of those services that you can use and just add some code to them using docker `volumes`. Just look for them at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/).
Example of use with exiting [Python Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) are already in its description. It even shows how to create your own Docker Image using a `Dockerfile` which you need for each image.

**Option 2:**
You can build just one image using a less specific image (let's say debian/ubuntu), install all interpreters, libraries and other requirements inside and then create an `ENTRYPOINT` which will call a script that will run each service and keep open to avoid the container finalisation.